# Connecting to the sftp server hosted in Windows from Linux

Tags: rsync, scp, sftp, shared-folders

We have a directory (hosted on Windows) named "groupftp" that is shared and is accessible from our Linux server

We connect through it from our linux machine with the below `sftp` command and do `ls` with wildcard search which is going to go through a huge set of data and every run is taking around 50 mins to fetch the result set. Is there any other mechanism to connect to such shared drive using Rsync or Scp, I tried, it doesnt seems to work.

```
Oracle@cued007 -bash ~/sah_tst
$ sftp Oracle@groupftp
Oracle@groupftp's password:
Connected to groupftp.
sftp> ls 2*/*/*001
```

Comment: "_I tried, it doesnt seems to work_" - What error message (if any)? What happened? On Windows, what service is running SFTP?

Answer (score 0):

Mount it as a file share using samba/cifs

Mount it as a sshfs share - you'll need to get creative with owner and group and permissions for it to be a true share

But... one does have to ask Why you need to do "ls *" and such? Why do all the files have to be in one directory, instead of organized (somewhat) into subdirectories?